# Mysterious Large White Space Below Web Page In Firefox Android Browser

Tags: android, firefox, browser

There is a mysterious very large and scrollable white space appearing below my web page in Firefox Android browser. It only occurs in Firefox Android Browser and every other desktop browser or android browser doesn't show the large white space.

When I tap any text input field on the page to make the keyboard appear and then deselect the text input field to dismiss the keyboard the white space disappears. And when I add the not recommended "user-scalable=no" to the viewport meta tag the white space disappears. Also when I Put the Firefox browser in the background by pressing my phone's home key and then open the browser again the white disappears. When the large white space disappears by doing all I stated above it comes back again when I reload the page.

I have searched for a problem like this and the solution but I could not find any. Please what could be responsible for this scrollable large white space below my web page only occurring in Firefox android browser?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issue on some webpages I've created. I've found out that it was because some content (mostly block content, not inline) in my footer caused the footer to overflow for some reason. Then I've added

```css
.footer-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to my CSS and the whitespace dissapeared. Try if this works for you.